# Download File and send email in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

How to exceute code after response.redirect?
I want to force file download using response.redirect , once the file is downloaded i wanted to show modal pop up to send email.

but after response.redirect the popup is not getting called.
Pls help me how to do this,

Thanks

**UPDATE:**
Thanks for your reply.
I am doing like this. any suggestions?

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + FileName.Name);
                long FileSize = myFile.Length;
                byte[] Buffer = new byte[(int)FileSize];
                myFile.Read(Buffer, 0, (int)FileSize);
                myFile.Close();

                Response.BinaryWrite(Buffer);
                // Response.Redirect(filepath,false);
                Response.Flush();
                Response.Close();
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "ShowPopup", "window.setTimeout('PopupModal()',50);", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't, unless the code you wish to execute is called on entering the location specified when using `Response.Redirect`. Once you transfer control, that's it, you end the response - the executing context is no longer and wherever you have transferred to takes over.

If you want to push a file down the wire, take a look at `Response.WriteFile` instead, this way you can have them download the file and continue executing your code, all within a single page, or at least transferring control between pages which carry specific actions; here's the [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.writefile.aspx) for more information.